# Cannot call webservice exposed by Mule

Tags: mule

I am using Mule to expose a web service and deployed it on AWS .  It's working fine locally. I can use SoapUI to test http://localhost:8087/hello. But if we call from outside using the host of AWS: http://xxx.xxx.com:8087/hello, it will show connection error. We've opened the port 8087, what else do we need? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined "localhost" in you mule configuration file mule will only listen on the localhost interface. Change the host in your inbound endpoint to 0.0.0.0 to bind to all available interfaces or explicitly specify the IP you want to listen on for incoming requests. 

If this doesn't fix it please verify firewall settings again and then post more information such as relevant parts of you mule configuration file.